# How to get current place request on (client) startup?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

In my `ApplicationBootstrapper implements Bootstrapper` I have access to the injected `PlaceManager`:

```java
public class ApplicationBootstrapper implements Bootstrapper {

    private PlaceManager placeManager;

    @Inject
    public ApplicationBootstrapper(PlaceManager placeManager) {
        this.placeManager = placeManager;
    }
}
```

However, if I try to reveal the place that is set in the place manager like this:

```java
private void revealRequestedPlaceAfterBootstrapping() { 
    PlaceRequest currentPlaceRequest = this.placeManager.getCurrentPlaceRequest();
    this.placeManager.revealPlace(currentPlaceRequest );
}
```

it's not working. The reason appears to be that the `currentPlaceRequest` does not contain any information about the current URL that's being accessed leaving me with an empty web page.

What am I doin wrong? How can I reveal the requested place as my application is starting up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert but I believe you are trying to get a `PlaceRequest` before one exists. Try just calling:

`placeManager.revealCurrentPlace()` - this will reveal the page the user has tried to access (most likely your homepage if there is nothing after the # in the url).

**OR**

`placeManager.revealDefaultPlace()` - this will reveal whatever you set to your default place in your `ClientModule`.

See [Revealing Places](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/core/navigation/reveal-places.html) and [Initialize GIN](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/get-started/from-scratch/Create-Files.html#gin) for more information.

*Good luck and have fun!*

Answer (score -2):

If I understood you correctly, this will help you, you're missing the history part of the deal.

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html#Putting_it_all_together

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    ClientFactory clientFactory = GWT.create(ClientFactory.class);
    EventBus eventBus = clientFactory.getEventBus();
    PlaceController placeController = clientFactory.getPlaceController();

    // Start ActivityManager for the main widget with our ActivityMapper
    ActivityMapper activityMapper = new AppActivityMapper(clientFactory);
    ActivityManager activityManager = new ActivityManager(activityMapper, eventBus);
    activityManager.setDisplay(appWidget);

    // Start PlaceHistoryHandler with our PlaceHistoryMapper
    AppPlaceHistoryMapper historyMapper= GWT.create(AppPlaceHistoryMapper.class);
    PlaceHistoryHandler historyHandler = new PlaceHistoryHandler(historyMapper);
    historyHandler.register(placeController, eventBus, defaultPlace);

    RootPanel.get().add(appWidget);
    // Goes to the place represented on URL else default place
    historyHandler.handleCurrentHistory();
}
```

Comment: This is using the generic GWT Activities and Places, and not GWT-Platform as the user has asked.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I completely missed that part, thanks for clearing it up.